# how to suppress error code 2893 in wix

Tags: wix

If the installation directory path is more than 100 chars. The installation fails without throwing any alert message to the user.

With this service pack we need to pop up an alert message saying the “Installation directory should not be more than 100 chars

Answer (score 1):

Add a custom action that evaluates the troublesome paths and calls ::MsiProcessMessage().